# Google places adding event invalid request

Tags: android, events, request, google-places-api

I'm trying to add an event in google places and the JSON returned has an invalid request in status and this endpoint has been removed in error_message. This morning it has worked correctly but now it doesn't work anymore.
I tried to use HTTP in the request to see if it returns the request denied but this doesn't do it, it always returns invalid request.

Here is my code:

```
private final String EVENT_URL =
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/event/add/json?";

private JSONObject uploadEvent() {

    JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
    StringEntity sEntity = null;
    try {
        jsonobj.put("duration", duration);
        jsonobj.put("reference", reference);
        jsonobj.put("summary", description);
        if(url.length() > 0){
            jsonobj.put("url", url);
        }           
         sEntity = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(getUrlEvent());     

    httppostreq.setEntity(sEntity);

    String responseText;
    JSONObject JSON = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);
        responseText = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
        JSON = new JSONObject(responseText);                    
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}

 private String getUrlEvent(){
    //genero la solicitud como la debajo descrita
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder(EVENT_URL);
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);       

    return urlString.toString();
}
```

Can anyone helps me please?

Comment: someone knows if the events api works now??? https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/add-place#deprecation

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sEntity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
sEntity.setContentType("application/json");



httppostreq.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: nothing. Im using in my variables this: duration = 3000; reference = the reference of the place when I use a place details search; summary = a string text; previously worked fine but now does not. could be something of the google account api or an expires key or something?

Comment: I found this, Note: Events and place bumps were deprecated on September 3, 2014. The deprecation period has now ended. As of February 10th, 2015, the API no longer accepts event or bump actions, and no longer returns events in Place Search or Place Details responses. here is the link, is this service really deprecated? https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/add-place#deprecation

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/add-place):

> **Note**: Events and place bumps were deprecated on September 3, 2014. The deprecation period has now ended. As of February 10th, 2015, the
>   API no longer accepts event or bump actions, and no longer returns
>   events in Place Search or Place Details responses.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I guess then is final. I'm doing an application to search sites and if they have some event, is showed but no longer works. any idea how I could do this, using this google api or another one?. I happen just use google sql to add the id of sites that can add events and then pick them up every time I do a search for sites.but I think it would be too slow.